# location available after few seconds after enable location services

Tags: android

I have a button, each time user click on it, I call the javascriptinterface `getLocation()`, if location services is off, brings user to settings let user turn it on.

I get the location by `onConnected` and `onLocationChanged`. Each time I open my app, the `onConnected` gets fired and will get the location. But I noticed that when I enable the Location Services from settings, and come back to app immediately, the `onConnected` gets fired, but location is still `null`. Looks like there's a delay or something. Until after about 3 seconds then I try again, it will work and get the location for me.

Here is my related code:

Android side:

```
protected Location location;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    ......
}

// JavaScript Interface for location on Pick Listing Page
public class LocationInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getLocation() throws JSONException
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        if (location != null)
        {
            json.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
            json.put("lon", location.getLongitude());
            return(json.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return(null);
    }
}

......//many override lifecycle methods here

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation)
{
    location = newLocation;
}
```

My question is, how can I get the location without a delay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you request location updates in the activity's **onStart()** so that when you return from the location settings the activity will request location updates.

Comment: add this: `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);` ?

Comment: Would you please share your logcat output?

Comment: when I return from the settings, the activity fires `onConnected`, which tries to getLastLocation. Is it not enough? I noticed there's just a few seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way out eventually:

add one condition for `getLocation()`:

```
....
    if (location != null)
    {
        ....
    }
    else if (location == null && isLocationEnabled(context)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (location == null && (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime) < 5000)
        {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        }
        if (location != null)
        {
            json.put("lat", location.getLatitude());
            json.put("lon", location.getLongitude());
            return(json.toString());
        }
        return(null);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent intent = ....
        ....
    }
    return(null);
```